# Can you bind a rails 3.2 app server to a specific IP addy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482356/is-there-a-way-to-stop-rails-built-in-server-from-listening-on-0-0-0-0-by-defau/8482398#8482398) suggested that you can bind a rails server to the ip 127.0.0.1 with the following syntax:

```
rails s --binding=127.0.0.1
```

Each attempt generates a rails options help screen. Binding is nowhere to be found. Does this option still exist? Is there another way? I am using Thin to serve up the app.

Comment: The `--binding` option does exist in [3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb) and [4.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb) branches. Can you run any other `rails` commands, like `rails console` without getting the help screen?

Comment: @user2062950, Yup. Rails s. Rails g something. And rails console. NP.