# What could be stopping rails from starting when using 'ASSET_HOST'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip

This is probably a bit of a newbie question but I'm trying to run some tests using a virtual machine and so I'm trying to use `ASSET_HOST=“x.x.x.x" rails s` to force the site to be available via my machine's IP address but the server just doesn't seem to start (I'm not using x.x.x.x but my machine's local IP address) - It starts fine using just `rails s` but just sits there when I try to use `ASSET_HOST`.

I'm not expecting anyone to solve the problem for me but a pointer in the right direction or list of things to check would be most helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asset_host just sets the url of where to look for "assets".  Not sure why you want to change the ip of the rails server.  I run rails in virtual box every day and just use the default.  Just type rails s and then use localhost:3000 in your browser.  Maybe you forgot to specify the port?

If you are really trying to change the IP of the rails server, this may help:

```
rails s -b <ip address>
```

From:

[Is there a way to stop Rails' built-in server from listening on 0.0.0.0 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482356/is-there-a-way-to-stop-rails-built-in-server-from-listening-on-0-0-0-0-by-defau)

Comment: Absolutely right! I did forget to set the port - this is why I love stack exchange - Thank you so much!