# rails server not responding to remote connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails server on a remote box (debian wheezy, ruby 2.2, rails 4.2) and the server does not respond when I try to connect to it in my local browser or curl. The request times out. However when I ssh into the box and `wget localhost:3000` it gets me the root page perfectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked firewall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 4.2 changed the default IP address that `rails server` binds to, instead of binding to `0.0.0.0` (ie. all interfaces) it binds only to `localhost`.

#### Edit

Sorry, I see now that you made no mention of production, just a remote box. So I removed that bit from above.

To get around this you can do two things, either always start with the -b option:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Or, there's a little trick to add that to the default, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998401/152786 (note that you only need to merge in the `:Port` and `:Host` options, and you can set the `:Host` to `0.0.0.0` if you want).

Comment: Oh my god, I wasted so much time thinking I couldn't access my server because of a router/firewall/iptables issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it was a nasty, unannounced change.

Answer (score 0):

To bind the server without using command arguments you can append this to `bin/rails` after line `require_relative '../config/boot'` and the code is executed only for the rails server command:

```
if ARGV.first == 's' || ARGV.first == 'server'
  require 'rails/commands/server'
  module Rails
    class Server
      def default_options
        super.merge(Host:  '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `bin/rails` file loks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'

# Set default host and port to rails server
if ARGV.first == 's' || ARGV.first == 'server'
  require 'rails/commands/server'
  module Rails
    class Server
      def default_options
        super.merge(Host:  '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
      end
    end
  end
end

require 'rails/commands'
```